# Can we hear media and make call simultaneously using two bluetooth devices?

Tags: android-10, bluetooth-audio

The picture says both are active.

[image]

Device : redmi note 7 pro

Comment: No... You select one device or the other as the active device, that's the way Android works.

Comment: What about [this](https://mobilesyrup.com/2018/03/08/android-p-connect-five-bluetooth-audio-devices-at-once/#:~:text=For%20example%2C%20Android%20Police%20have,of%20connected%20Bluetooth%20audio%20devices)?

Comment: Never made it into a full release... Google has been known to try some crazy things in their betas, and some make it to release, but most of these features do not. There isn't much actual practical application for this feature, and it never made it to a production release. That was a couple versions ago and it never happened and there is no demand, the chances it will happen now are near zero.